# Generic iPhone Push Application

Tags: iphone, push, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

This is not a development-based question.

I am looking for an iPhone application which can offer a push protocol to my iPhone via is API.  I mean lets say I will integrate its API to my arbitrary program and I'll push some notifications via API then its client running on my iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad will show me the notifications.

Is there such a generic application provides push protocol (maybe authenticating with a secret key or username-pass). If there is not any, this would be a great app idea.

Comment: Your app won't be able to send push notifications if a user doesn't have this app installed.

Comment: The user is just me and I will install app providing such a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, again I found out some of them:

- http://boxcar.io/
- http://howlapp.com/
- http://prowl.weks.net/

Comment: Also https://pushover.net/ . you can even have critical alerts that repeats until user acknowledge the message.